# How exactly do interfaces work in Go?

Tags: go

After reading the spec, and the "Effective Go" section on them, I still don't quite understand how interfaces work in Go.

Like, where do you define them? How does interface enforcement work? And is there a way to specify somewhere that an object implements an interface, as opposed to simply defining the methods in the interface?

Apologies for the beginner question; but I really am struggling to understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some good posts on interfaces over at [Russ Cox](http://research.swtch.com/2009/12/go-data-structures-interfaces.html) and [Ian Lance Taylor's](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/277) blog which i recommend checking out. They'll probably cover your questions and more ...

I think a good conceptual example is the [net](http://golang.org/pkg/net/) package. There you'll find a connections interface([Conn](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/net.go#L22)), which is implemented by the [TCPConn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#TCPConn), the [UnixConn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#UnixConn), and the [UDPConn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPConn). The Go pkg source is probably the best documentation for the Go language.

Comment: Those posts are excellent. Thanks for the other resources as well.

Comment: Hope you enjoy Go. There are ALOT of QA's in the go-nuts mailing-list as well, which is very active.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you define an interface like this:

```
type InterfaceNameHere interface {
    MethodA(*arg1, *arg2)
    MethodB(*arg3)
}
```

That particular interface definition requires anything which implements the interface to have both a `MethodA` method that takes 2 arguments, and a `MethodB` method that takes 1 argument.

Once you've defined it, Go will automatically check when you try to use something where a certain interface is required, whether the thing you're using satisfies that interface. You don't have to explicitly state that a given thing satisfies a given interface, it's just automatically checked when you try to utilize something in a scenario where it's expected to satisfy it.

Comment: Where do you put the type `InterfaceType interface { ... }` though? In your `main` package?

Comment: Wherever you'd plan on using it - the scoping works just like anything else.

Comment: Go's interfaces let you use duck typing like you would in a purely dynamic language like Python but still have the compiler catch obvious mistakes.

Comment: @Simon It's not duck typing, it's structural typing, which is far more restrictive. With duck typing, you can invoke method foo on any object that implements foo, and you can usually add such methods to objects at runtime. With interfaces, the variable on which you invoke an interface method must be of the interface type -- a static type, a notion that doesn't exist in dynamic duck-typed languages.